# Docker image dns issue, name solve failed

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dns, resolve

When I run a latest ubuntu image as a container, its apt-get update failed.

**It showed me a "Temporary failure resovling 'archive.ubuntu.com'".**

Then I tried the solution as below

**echo "91.189.92.201 archive.ubuntu.com" >> /etc/hosts**

But this can only work for "archive.ubuntu.com" and only for once, it cannot solve other name solve.

If i want the container to link any website, i need to do the similar work as above to add the website's ip address and name to /etc/hosts/

I doubt it was a dns problem, so I tried the solution as below.

[image]

By adding "DOCKER_OPTS="--dns   --dns", and the result was nothing like i wanted.

[image]

I want the containers in Ubuntu docker can connect to every website, i thought it would be a problem about that the container doesn't have the ability to resolve the website names.

Comment: The error message was spelling it _resovling_?

Answer (score 0):

1.please make sure that you can access 8.8.8.8 on the docker host itself.if can't,change 8.8.8.8 to a valid dns server address.
2.check iptables. iptables-save should have one rule:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
to enable container SNAT and DNAT.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137432/discussion-on-answer-by-jianjian-feng-docker-image-dns-probem-name-solve-failed).